# Unique union of array values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents where each document has an array of subjects. I want to be able to find the unique subjects where the user_id is in a list.

Example document store:

```
{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "subjects" : [
        123,
        456,
        789
    ]
}
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "subjects" : [
        789,
        111,
        555
    ]
}
{
    "user_id" : "3",
    "subjects" : [
        123,
        111
    ]
}
```

So I might want all the unique subjects where the user_id is in (1,2), so the result would be:

```
{
    "subjects" : [
        123,
        456,
        789,
        111,
        555
    ]
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) query to do this:

```js
db.test.distinct('subjects', {user_id: {$in: ['1', '2']}})
```

The first parameter is the field to get the distinct values for, and the second parameter selects the documents from which the do this.

Comment: Ha! I wasn't aware `distinct` would merge arrays! This is a much better solution than mine!

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Yeah, it's more a more flexible command than it first appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.test.aggregate(
    {
        $match: // filters results based on the list of IDs
        {
            user_id: { $in: [ "1", "2" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$subjects" // unwinds the `subjects` array
    },
    {
        $group: // groups the unwound elements back into a single array
        {
            _id: 1,
            subjects: { $addToSet: "$subjects" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { subjects: 1, _id: 0 }
    }
)
```

This will be returned:

```
{ "subjects" : [ 555, 111, 789, 456, 123 ] }
```